# Does black-box automation testing make sense in variable application setups?

Tags: automated-testing

So in a company that lets say has a mish-mash of various technologies, back-end and front-end. Does it make sense to NOT tie automation code closely with the application?

I am facing a dilemma where I need to train Manual testers to use automation, but each application has a different tech stack.

To me it makes sense to have something automation wise that's more external rather than tied to the application. Integration/Unit testing is great within an application however training QA's to learn multiple technologies seems daunting.

In this sense does it make more sense to use something like Postman for API testing and whatever UI framework (playwright/cypress) or do you think it's better to expect QA's to learn close to application unit/integration testing?

Comment: What is/are the testing problem(s) you need to solve using automation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of whether black-box automation testing makes sense in variable application setups is a complex one, and the answer depends on a number of factors.

First, it's important to understand the difference between black-box and white-box testing. Black-box testing is a method of testing where the tester has no knowledge of the internal workings of the application being tested. The tester is focused solely on the inputs and outputs of the application. White-box testing, on the other hand, involves testing the internal workings of the application, such as the code and the database.

In a variable application setup, black-box testing can be a useful approach. Since each application has a different tech stack, it may not be feasible or efficient for QA's to learn multiple technologies in order to write close-to-application unit/integration tests. In this case, using tools like Postman for API testing and UI frameworks like Playwright or Cypress for UI testing can be a good option. These tools are designed to be more external and can work with a variety of tech stacks.

However, it's important to note that black-box testing does have its limitations. Since the tester has no knowledge of the internal workings of the application, it may be more difficult to identify specific issues or bugs. This is where white-box testing can be useful. By testing the internal workings of the application, QA's can identify issues at a more granular level.

Ultimately, the best approach will depend on the specific needs and requirements of your company and your applications. It may make sense to use a combination of black-box and white-box testing, depending on the situation. The most important thing is to choose a testing approach that is effective and efficient, and that allows you to identify and address issues as quickly and effectively as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Black-box computerization testing can be helpful in factor application arrangements, contingent upon the particular setting and objectives of the testing system. Black-box testing alludes to a strategy where the inner functions of the application under test are not known to the analyzer. All things considered, the analyzer centers around the data sources and results of the framework to approve its way of behaving.

In factor application arrangements, where the designs, conditions, or information data sources can change, Black-box testing can assist with guaranteeing that the application acts true to form under various circumstances. The following are a couple of contemplations:

Functional Testing: Black-box testing can be powerful in approving the practical prerequisites of the application across different arrangements. By giving data sources and noticing the results, analyzers can confirm that the application works accurately no matter what the fundamental arrangement.

Regression Testing: When changes are made to the application or its current circumstance, relapse testing is essential to guarantee that current usefulness stays unaffected. Black-box computerization testing can help in rapidly executing a set-up of tests confirming that the application actually acts true to form.

Compatibility Testing: Variable application arrangements might include different working frameworks, programs, or gadgets. Black-box testing can assist survey the similarity of the application with these different conditions by approving its conduct across numerous designs.

User Experience Testing: Black-box testing can be valuable in assessing the client experience of the application in factor arrangements. Analyzers can zero in on angles like convenience, responsiveness, and openness without requiring point by point information on the inside execution.

Nonetheless, it's essential to take note of that black-box testing has restrictions. It may not be appropriate for revealing low-level deformities or execution gives that require information on the inner operations. In such cases, a mix of black-box and white-box testing (where the interior design is known) may be more proper.

Eventually, the decision of testing approach relies upon the particular goals, requirements, and accessible assets. It's frequently useful to have a balanced testing system that incorporates a blend of various methods to guarantee complete inclusion.